# Regex Group Multiple Lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST, DB_PASSWORD from a WordPress file using regex. Is there a way to group each variable into its own group?

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'stack');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Result should be grouped like this: wordpress, root, stack, localhost
There should be 4 matches.

Comment: `define\('DB_NAME', '(.*?)'\)`

I got this far, I tried to group doing this `(define\('DB_NAME', '(.*?)'\))(define\('DB_USER', '(.*?)'\))` but not match comes back.

Comment: I don't understand well what you want, could you add the desired result. What language or tool are you using?

Comment: What language/tool/command line are you using?

Comment: I've updated the question, there should be four matches.

Comment: In ServiceNow, you may use the pattern from the answer with `match`: `while (match != null) { matches.push(match); match = reg.match(); ...}`, and if you use capturing groups, you will be able to access the first one with `[1]`, the second with `[2]`, etc.

Comment: Are the spaces after the commas obligatory?

Answer (score 2):

The below regex is what you're looking for.

```
define\('DB_(?:NAME|USER|PASSWORD|HOST)', ?'(.*)'\);
```

It matches entire statements (because JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds) this way:

- `define\(` is the beginning (note the backslash before the parenthesis)
- `'DB_(?:NAME|USER|PASSWORD|HOST)'` is the variable name
- `, ?` is the delimiter between the variable name and the actual value
- `'(.*)'` is the actual value (use `'(.+)'` if the values aren't allowed to be empty)
- `\);` is the end (again, note the backslash before the parenthesis)

Note that the actual value is in a capture group ([kudos to Casimir et Hippolyte for suggesting this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235558/regex-group-multiple-lines/39235970#comment65809070_39235970)). Not only this is easier to set up than lookarounds, but it works on JS unlike [what I came up previously](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39235970/2).

Comment: It's a good idea but don't forget to capture the value content (with a capture group). You should also explain how to use it.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte `'.*'` does that.

Comment: @BrandonWilson: to see what happens with a global research , add the g modifier in regex101: https://regex101.com/r/yW8aL3/1

Comment: @dorukayhan: Yes `'.*'` describes the value part, but it gives no way to extract it from the whole match.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/aY2kY2/2 updated the demo, however, ServiceNow doesn't support modifiers. I need to have each variable in a different groups so ServiceNow can use them.

Comment: @BrandonWilson: I don't know ServiceNow, but to be clear, you are looking for a pattern that extract all the values you want in one time? In this case why do you use a the javascript tag? Does ServiceNow use the same regex flavour than Javascript?

Comment: Correct and yes service now should l uses the same regex.

Comment: @BrandonWilson: In this case build a pattern that describes all substring you want. The order in a wordpress config file is always the same, you only need to take in account and to describe "useless" comment lines and blank lines between "interesting" lines.